# Async => avoiding deadlock and writing slow performing async code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have this class with two public async methods, which also calls some private methods that are async.

**Here's the class:**

```
public class AggregatedDataService
{
public async Task<OrganizationAggregatedInfo> GetOrganizationAggregatedInfo(int organizationId)
{
    var organization = await GetOrganization(organizationId);
    var organizationContact = await GetOrganizationContact(organization.ID);
    var associations = await GetOrganizationAssociations(organization.ID);

    //await Task.WhenAll(organizationContact, associations);
    return new OrganizationAggregatedInfo(organization.Name, organization.Address, organizationContact,
        associations);
}

public async Task<SchoolAggregatedInfo> GetSchoolAggreagtedInfo(int schoolId)
{
    if(schoolId < 1)
        return null;

    var school = await GetSchool(schoolId);
    if (school == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var getSchoolAddressTask = GetSchoolAddress(schoolId); 
    var getMemberSchoolsTask = GetMemberSchools(schoolId);
    var getSchoolCurriculumTask = GetSchoolCurriculum(schoolId);
    var getSchoolFacilitiesTask = GetSchoolFacilities(schoolId);
    var getSchoolAssociationsTask = GetSchoolAssociations(schoolId);
    var getSchoolAcreditationsTask = GetSchoolAcreditations(schoolId);
    var getGovernanceStructureTask = GetGovernanceStructure(schoolId);

    await Task.WhenAll(getSchoolAddressTask, getMemberSchoolsTask, getSchoolCurriculumTask,
            getSchoolFacilitiesTask, getSchoolAssociationsTask, getSchoolAcreditationsTask,
            getGovernanceStructureTask);

    var schoolAddress = getSchoolAddressTask.Result;
    var memberSchools = getMemberSchoolsTask.Result; 
    var teacherInfo = await GetTeacherInformation(schoolAddress.SchoolID);
    var curriculum = getSchoolCurriculumTask.Result;
    var facilities = getSchoolFacilitiesTask.Result;
    var associations = getSchoolAssociationsTask.Result;
    var accreditations = getSchoolAcreditationsTask.Result;
    var studentInfo = await GetStudentInformation(schoolAddress.SchoolID);
    var governanceStructure = getGovernanceStructureTask.Result; 

    SchoolContactReadView contact = null;

    if (schoolAddress != null)//TODO: consider using null propagation
    {
        if (schoolAddress.SchoolContact != null)
            contact = SchoolContactReadView.ShowSchoolContactView(schoolAddress.SchoolContact);
    }

    var schoolAggregateInfo = new SchoolAggregatedInfo
    {
        Name = school.Name,
        Address = school.Address,
        MemberSchoolsCount = memberSchools.Count(),
        GovernanceStructure = governanceStructure,
        Accreditations = accreditations.ToList(),
        Associations = associations.ToList(),
        Contact = contact,
        Curriculum = curriculum,
        Facilities = facilities.ToList()
    };

    return schoolAggregateInfo;
}

private async Task<List<OrganizationAssociationReadView>> GetOrganizationAssociations(int organizationId)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/organization/associations/" + organizationId);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var contentResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<OrganizationAssociation>>();
        associations = contentResult.Select(OrganizationAssociationReadView.MapFrom).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}

private async Task<OrganizationContactReadView> GetOrganizationContact(int organizationId)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/organization/contact/" + organizationId);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var contentResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrganizationContact>();
        var organizationContactReadView = OrganizationContactReadView.MapFrom(contentResult);

        organizationContact = organizationContactReadView;
    }
    else
    {
        _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}

private async Task<OrganizationReadView> GetOrganization(int organizationId)
{
    same as the other other methods....
}

private async Task<GovernanceStructureReadView> GetGovernanceStructure(int schoolId)
{
    ....
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<AccreditationReadView>>  GetSchoolAcreditations(int schoolId)
{
    ....
}

.... all other method ....          
}
```

and I also consume this method e.g

```
var obj = await GetSchoolAggreagtedInfo(21).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I feel like I have too much `async` methods and which I'm afraid may cause more harm than good.

Is there a better way of doing all this async stuff (maybe a pattern), or is the code OK?

Comment: "each await spins off new thread(from my understanding of async and await)." – well that's not true. In principle async methods will run on some existing thread, but it depends on your context. Are you on a UI thread? The async callbacks will generally also run on the UI thread. Are you in a console app/web server? Callbacks will generally run on a thread pool thread (but not create a new one for every task.)

Comment: [Asynchronous Programming in C# : Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) by Eric Lippert is a good post to read - "The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible"

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you asking - whether async/await is completely untested and case errors and deadlock - that is really unlikely; can one call such code and cause deadlocks - yes ; does code look reasonable - yes (but CodeReview may be more appropriate site) . The second question can't be answered on SO at all as you did not define "better" criteria...

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever that articles helped clear the misunderstanding

Comment: This would be a good fit for us if you can demonstrate that there are no issues when the program operates within normal parameters (I'm not entirely sure at what point deadlocks become "problems within normal parameters", YMMV) and if you include the omitted code. If you do not do these things, it will be closed on CR as broken or example code respectively

Comment: Unless you have a specific need to marshal back to the calling thread, you should use ConfigureAwait(false) when awaiting.

The only time I don't use ConfigureAwait(false) is when I'm going to modify a Model that has bindings that trigger an update to a UI which demands that any changes are made from a specific thread.